# Ui mask value not matching ng model

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

Hi I am using a ui mask to format a phone number in an input box.  Problem is the ngmodel is not matching what I see on the screen. For example:

```
 <input type="text"  ui-mask="999-999-9999"  placeholder="xxx-xxx-xxxx"class="form-control" data-ng-model="search.phone"   maxlength="12" >
```

what i see on screen: 778-673-7892
ng-model value: 7786737892

How do I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this has been completed, but I don't know if it has been officially released yet.  Try doing this:

```
<input type="text"  ui-mask="999-999-9999"  placeholder="xxx-xxx-xxxx" class="form-control" data-ng-model="search.phone"   maxlength="12" ui-mask-use-viewvalue="true">
```

If it doesn't work, you can make the changes yourself, you just have to find the file the mask directive is in, and make the changes you see [here](https://github.com/Snede/ui-utils/commit/7485a1db0c78a2afd970927b88e06eb3b0bc4654)

Comment: But clear button of input is not clearing model value?

Answer (score 8):

This is a little out-of-date, for those looking at the latest ui-mask (1.2, it may be in older versions as well), the official attribute that it's observing is "modelViewValue". Example:

```
<input type="text" ui-mask="999-999-9999" placeholder="xxx-xxx-xxxx" ng-model="search.phone" model-view-value="true">
```

This will preserve your model value to include look of the mask.